# In Oracle Apex how do you set the table name of a report using a page item?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have many tables to choose from, and an Interactive Report whose table name needs to be set using a page item called P4_TABLE_NAME.

Other posts say that this can only be done with PL/SQL. So I set the Source of the Interactive Report to "Function Body returning SQL Query" and the Language to PL/SQL. This is the code I then used:

```
declare
    v_query varchar2(500);
begin
    v_query := 'select * from '||:P4_TABLE_NAME ;
    return v_query;
end;
```

This code gives the error "*invalid table name*". I also tried it on a Classic Report and it gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's kind of *tricky* because report should know which columns you're selecting **unless** you set it to use **generic column names**. It means that no matter which table you query, column names will be `col1, col2, col3`, ...

Here's how:

- I created a new page with a Classic report region and a Select list item (which returns tables I have in my schema)
- report's source is a function body that returns a query, just as you put it:

  ```
  declare
      v_query varchar2(500);
  begin
      v_query := 'select * from ' || :P4_TABLE_NAME;
      return v_query;
  end;
  ```
- don't forget to set "Use generic column names" to "Yes"!

Item is trivial:

- I set it to "Submit page" (so that when I choose a new table, report's contents changes)
- Select list item's query:

  ```
  select table_name d, table_name r
  from user_tables
  order by table_name
  ```

Run the page:

[image]

Comment: "Use generic column names" to "Yes" " seems to be only available for Classic Report?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes.

Comment: Well, it worked. Shame it can't be done with Interactive Report. Thanks anyway.